# Using mhchem and chemfig: how to make image smaller and let it fit vertically?

Tags: chemfig, mhchem

**Code**

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemfig,stackengine,graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor,tikz}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\definesubmol{wallpart}{-[:-90,.5](-[:110,.5])}
\definesubmol{wall}{!{wallpart}!{wallpart}!{wallpart}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[10]

\begin{align}
\cee{CH3 + \varphi &-> \varphi CH3}\\
\cee{\varphi CH3 +e &-> }\chemfig{!{wall}(-[:0]**6(---(-CH3)---)) !{wall}}
\end{align}

\lipsum[20]

\end{document}
```

**Product**

[image: Product benzene ring]

**Trouble shooter**

As you can see, the image (chemfig) is maybe a little too big. I don't know how to make it smaller.

I would also like to have the equation before the chemfig to be vertically centered to the chemfig image.

*In the meantime, thank you so much for your attention and participation.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Citing `chemfig`'s manual

> ChemFig always places the first atom of the molecule on the baseline
>   of the preceding code.

This means that the first atom in a molecule determines the baseline of the whole molecule. A solution in this case it is rather easy: add an invisible bond upwards before the “wall” (i.e. three bonds scaled by .5 going down (the angle is `:-90`)) starts:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\definesubmol{wallpart}{-[:-90,.5](-[:110,.5])}
\definesubmol{wall}{!{wallpart}!{wallpart}!{wallpart}}

\begin{document}

A \chemfig{
  -[:90,1.5,,,draw=none]
  !{wall}
  (-[:0]**6(---(-CH_3)---))
  !{wall}
} B

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you also add a phantom atom at the beginning the alingment fits the preceding and following text:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\definesubmol{wallpart}{-[:-90,.5](-[:110,.5])}
\definesubmol{wall}{!{wallpart}!{wallpart}!{wallpart}}

\begin{document}

A \chemfig{
  \vphantom{A}-[:90,1.5,,,draw=none]
  !{wall}
  (-[:0]**6(---(-CH_3)---))
  !{wall}
} B

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make the molecule smaller by setting the atom sep to a smaller value

```
\setatomsep{1.5em}
```

(default is 3em) or scale it using the optional arguments: `\chemfig[scale=.5][scale=.5]{...}`. Try using only one of the optional arguments to see their different effects…